# tastypie display raw foreign key id value

Tags: django, tastypie

I'm doing my best to return values of related record ids (foreign key reference) using tastypie. By default, foreign keys are filtered out from the result.

I've got a following model:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    """Finance category"""
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'category'
    parent = models.ForeignKey('self')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    TYPES = (
        ('outcome', 'outcome'),
        ('income', 'income'),
    )
    type = models.CharField(max_length=7,choices=TYPES)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField()
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField()
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User, db_column='created_by', related_name='createdCategories')
    updated_by = models.ForeignKey(User, db_column='updated_by', related_name='updatedCategories')
```

I've got two relations here. `parent` is recursive relation (it's a category tree table). `created_by` is a relation to the user. API is returning following values:
 * id
 * name
 * created_at
 * updated_at
 * type
 * resource_uri

What can I do to make tastypie return parent(_id) or created_by (or just any foreign key)?

The following is what I've tried from another OS question:

```
class IncomeCategoryResource(ModelResource):
    parent_id = models.IntegerField(attribute="parent_id")
    class Meta:
        queryset = Category.objects.filter(type='income')
```

Unfortunately, the whole API fails:

```
__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'attribute'
```

I've also tried to replace `attribute` kwarg with `db_column`. This one is just ignored.

Help me, please :)

Answer (score 4):

First off, the `IntegerField` there is wrong. You should be using tastypie's fields (tastypie.fields), not django model fields (django.db.models). Then your resource should look like:

```
class IncomeCategoryResource(ModelResource):
    parent_id = IntegerField(attribute="parent__id")
    class Meta:
        queryset = Category.objects.filter(type='income')
```

Note the use of double underscore to get to the parent's id field.